# mediasource webm doesnt play right

Tags: javascript, html, video, xmlhttprequest, webm

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <video controls width="800"></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
//var assetURL = 'resources/vid/640x480_Q_crf_10_120s_tears_of_steel_1080p.webm';
var assetURL = 'resources/vid/frag_bunny.mp4';

//var mimeCodec = 'video/webm; codecs="vorbis, vp9"';
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
var sourceBuffer = null;

video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);


function sourceOpen() {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('get', assetURL);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Hello,
I have a problem with the Media Source Extensions.

As soon as I insert an mp4 video, the playback works perfectly. But when I embed a webm video, the first 5 - 8 seconds are played and the video is then stopped.

I don't understand why the code works perfectly with mp4 files, but not with webm (vp9) files.

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards

Comment: I have figured out the problem, but I do not have a solution. If I render the video with "ffmpeg -i xyz.webm -c:v vp9 -crf 10 -g 1 -b:v 600k -minrate: 300k -maxrate: 5000k -c:a libvorbis xyz_Q_g_1_minavgmax_300_600_5000_crf_10_2.webm" then it works. But if I do this without "-g 1" then it will not work. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: The video is most probably muxed badly, can you share the file, so others can inspect it? `-g 1` just sets the GOP length to 1, so that is not a fix.